# Why do i receive en error message when i open a dll library with ruby, using fiddle?

Tags: ruby, windows, dll, fiddle

On windows 10, i am using ruby 2.7.0.

Using 'fiddle', I try to open a dll in my ruby script but i receive an error message on line "Fiddle.dlopen".
There is my ruby code :

```
require 'fiddle'

filename = File.join(__dir__, "Circle.dll")
circle = Fiddle.dlopen(filename)

compute_ray = Fiddle::Function.new(
  circle['ComputeRay'],
  [Fiddle::TYPE_DOUBLE, Fiddle::TYPE_DOUBLE],
  Fiddle::TYPE_DOUBLE
)

r = compute_ray.call(100,5)
puts "ray = #{r}"
```

"Circle.dll" has been compiled from this repo : https://github.com/chaudard/Circle

There is the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from use_dll.rb:6:in `<main>'
    2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fiddle.rb:47:in `dlopen'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fiddle.rb:47:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fiddle.rb:47:in `initialize': /home/user/code/ruby/dll/Circle.dll: Exec format error (Fiddle::DLError)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The ELF header is usually a signal that it's an incorrectly matching platform. So Circle DLL might not be compatible with the platform you are trying to run and access it on.

Comment: you are right. I made a mistake when i posted the error message. This message occurs when i tried my code on ubuntu.
On windows, the error is not the same : "Exec format error (Fiddle::DLError)".
I have edited the original post - sorry for the mistake.

Comment: was Circle.dll compiled on Windows?

Comment: yes it was. (it is a delphi project)

Comment: Probably miscompiled the dll. Use dependency viewer to verify it's a DLL and built for the right architecture.

Comment: So i decided to create a new dll (c# .net , with visual studio 2019). The error message is now different : "Unknown symbol (Fiddle::DLError)". (I tested it in another c# .net console project and it works, so i think this time the dll is well compiled).